# asp.net forms authentication across applications

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a solution with an existing web forms website project (NOT web application project). I want to add a new mvc web application to the solution and have web forms site and mvc web app share forms authentication.  I followed the article from microsoft but on localhost this does not work.  In the solution, if I start both the webforms and mvc sites they have different port numbers for localhost so I authenticate in the webforms web site but the authentication cookie does not get picked up.  Is there something obvious I am missing?

[Forms Authentication Across Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

Comment: Too many things can go wrong in this scenario. First of all, you need to start with regular cookie. Can you read and write same cookie from both sites?

Comment: no because doesn't see those cookies as coming from the same domain.